# How can I force WPF to make data bindings without showing the window?

Tags: wpf, unit-testing, data-binding

I want to unit test a WPF application and one scenario is to check that data bindings are correct. The simple way to do that would be to create the form, force it to bind to data and then compare the values from the controls with the expected ones. Is there any way to do that?

Answer (score 0):

You can set the Window's Visibility property to Hidden.